# Boundary condition setup for the region defined with basic geometry

Tags: differential-equations, geometry

I have a region defined like this:

```
circle = Disk[{4.5, 3}, 0.5];
pin = Rectangle[{4, 0}, {5, 3}];
square = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {9, 9}];
region = RegionDifference[square, RegionUnion[circle, pin]];
```

Applying RegionPlot[region] gives this:

[image: Region]

Now I need to setup boundary conditions for this region the following way:

1) Top, left, right walls: u[x,y] == 0

2) Bottom wall 0 <= x < 4: u[x,y] == 0

3) Bottom wall 5 < x <= 0: u[x,y] == 0

4) Wall at x = 4, for 0 <= y < 3: u[x,y] == 10

5) Wall at x = 5, for 0 <= y < 3: u[x,y] == 10

6) Semicircle with the center at x = 4.5 and y = 3 (radius = 0.5): u[x,y] == 10

These boundary conditions should be applied to a Laplace equation:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0,
bc},
   u, {x, y} \[Element] region]

DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] region, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

---

Update 1: the result should be something like this:

[image: image2]

That is what I received when I ran the code provided by user21 on Mathematica 10.3. I introduced:

`mesh = ToElementMesh[DiscretizeRegion[region], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01];`

and in plotting I changed `Mesh -> All` (for the picture on the left)

---

Update 2: User21 provided a new part of the code:

```
DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, Mesh -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

It gives the same plot as what you can see in User21's answer but only if you use Mathematica of the version newer than 10.3. For the version 10.3 I get an error *"InterpolatingFunction::dmval: "Input value {-9.99857,-9.99857} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used."* And the plot looks like this:

[image: error]

It gets a bit better if I switch `{x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}` to `{x, y} \[Element] region` but still the plot looks unacceptable:

[image: error2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
circle = Disk[{4.5, 3}, 0.5];
pin = Rectangle[{4, 0}, {5, 3}];
square = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {9, 9}];
region = RegionDifference[square, RegionUnion[circle, pin]];
bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, 
    y == 0 || y == 9 || x == 0 || x == 9], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 10, (4 <= x <= 5) && y <= 4]};
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, bc}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] region];

DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] region, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

If you use a higher `MaxRecursion` the graphics get smoother:

```
DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] region, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]

It gets better when you use:

```
DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, Mesh -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]

Comment: I did the trick. Thanks! I have one extra question. How to make the result smoother? I try some codes straight from Mathematica website where the results look very smooth. When I execute them in my Mathematica 10.3, they look a bit "spiky" like this solution that you provided. I guess the mess needs to be denser?

Comment: Wait a second. Something is wrong. If I run this code, I see several messages from InterpolatingFunction "Input value {4.00619,3.02712} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used." And then there is a general message "Further output of InterpolatingFunction::dmval will be suppressed during this calculation." If I refine the mesh, the result looks the same because calculation stops at some point.

Comment: I noticed that rather than using a region for PDE solution, it is better to define mesh. I did that like this `mesh = ToElementMesh[DiscretizeRegion[region], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01];` As a result the simulation doesn't have any problems anymore.

Comment: @ViacheslavPlotnikov, no that is certainly the not the best approach. Remove the call to `DiscretizeRegion`

Comment: I see what happened here. I tried to call DiscretizeRegion and the result looked much better. But I did it today in Mathematica 10.3. There seem to be a great difference.

Comment: You used MaxRecursion but doesn't the solution still look spiky to you? Could you please use `Mesh -> All` and see what happens? I ran this solution in Mathematica 10.3 and everything looks much better. This has to do with how the new versions deal with regions. I think it is related to this post [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/144329/revisions)

Comment: @ViacheslavPlotnikov, I'd report that to WRI. This is not a problem with the FEM stuff but the visualization.

Comment: I will report it very soon. Thanks for your help!