# Zoom into RegionPlot of a region made with RegionDifference/RegionUnion

Tags: plotting, regions

I have a region defined like in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144279/boundary-condition-setup-for-the-region-defined-with-basic-geometry) question:

```
circle = Disk[{4.5, 3}, 0.5];
pin = Rectangle[{4, 0}, {5, 3}];
square = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {9, 9}];
region = RegionDifference[square, RegionUnion[circle, pin]];
```

`RegionPlot[region]` gives:

[image: regionplot]

Now I want to zoom into a semicircular opening. I attempt it like this:

`RegionPlot[region,{x,3,6},{y,2,6}]`

This doesn't work and gives an error:

> RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0,0},{9,9}],RegionUnion[Disk[{4.5,3},0.5],\
>   Rectangle[{4,0},{5,3}]]] should be a Boolean combination of \
>   equations, inequalities, and Element statements

What do I do to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RegionPlot` appears to be built with implicit regions in mind. To make it work you could use `Element`:

```
RegionPlot[Element[{x, y}, region], {x, 3, 6}, {y, 2, 6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But for zooming in, `PlotRange` also comes to mind. This requires no trickery:

```
RegionPlot[region, PlotRange -> {{3, 6}, {2, 6}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

You can intersect your region with a rectangle representing the zoom-in area.

```
zoomInRect = Rectangle[{3, 2}, {6, 6}];
zoomInView = RegionIntersection[region, zoomInRect];
RegionPlot[zoomInView]
```

[image: zoom_in]